# Add checkbox python tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I'm using 10.2.2 arcgis

I have the following script

```py
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\Users\Document\Geomarketing\Datos\20140826\rest\PG_Restaurantes_GT.shp")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "BOTTOM")
del mxd, addLayer
```

The function of this script is to add a specific layer to my dataframe.  I want to add this script into a model, my purpose is to have a checkbox to have the option to add or not to add the layer.

I am new to this and do not know what changes should I make to my script to let me do this in modelbuider.

Do I do this in my script?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create a boolean variable and define it as a model parameter.  This will add a check box option when double clicking on the model.

OR

Create a script tool that runs your code and has a boolean data type.

Either way you will have to check the boolean value using an if statement.